# Using Gatsby's Intercom plugin to integrate Intercom

Tags: gatsby, intercom

I've tried both https://github.com/toriihq/gatsby-plugin-intercom-spa and https://github.com/search?q=gatsby-plugin-intercom to try to integrate Intercom but have been unsuccessful.

The README for both these plugins state that I merely have to install the plugin via npm (in my case I use yarn add) and then update `gatsby-config.js` with the relevant code snippet (and use my Intercom app_id).

Are there other steps that need to be taken care of?

Comment: you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source of the https://github.com/toriihq/gatsby-plugin-intercom-spa plugin, it only shows up the intercom UI when `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production`.

Possibly, you were expecting it to load locally in your development environnment?

Comment: I'm the author of this plugin and indeed it is set to run only for production. If there's a need to run it in development mode as well, please open an issue on GitHub and we'll make sure to support it.